# Default Implementation of Objective-C Optional Protocol Methods

Tags: swift, protocols

How can I provide default implementations for Objective-C optional protocol methods?

Ex.

```
extension AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
  func speechSynthesizer(synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeechUtterance utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
    print(">>> did finish")
  }
}
```

Expectation: Whatever class that conforms to `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` should run the above function whenever a speech utterance finishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it just exactly as you've implemented it.  The difference ends up being in how the method is actually called.

Let's take this *very* simplified example:

```
@objc protocol FooProtocol {
    optional func bar() -> Int
}

class Omitted: NSObject, FooProtocol {}
class Implemented: NSObject, FooProtocol {
    func bar() -> Int {
        print("did custom bar")
        return 1
    }
}
```

By adding no other code, I'd expect to have to use this code as such:

```
let o: FooProtocol = Omitted()
let oN = o.bar?()

let i: FooProtocol = Implemented()
let iN = i.bar?()
```

Where `oN` and `iN` both end up having type `Int?`, `oN` is `nil`, `iN` is `1` and we see the text `"did custom bar"` print.

Importantly, not the optionally chained method call: `bar?()`, that question mark between the method name in the parenthesis.  This is how we must call optional protocol methods from Swift.

Now let's add an extension for our protocol:

```
extension FooProtocol {
    func bar() -> Int {
        print("did bar")
        return 0
    }
}
```

If we stick to our original code, where we optionally chain the method calls, there is no change in behavior:

[image]

*However*, with the protocol extension, we no longer have to optionally unwrap.  We can take the optional unwrapping out, and the extension is called:

[image]

The unfortunate problem here is that this isn't necessarily particularly useful, is it?  Now we're just calling the method implemented in the extension every time.

So there's one slightly better option *if* you're in control of the class making use of the protocol and calling the methods.  You can check whether or not the class responds to the selector:

```
let i: FooProtocol = Implemented()

if i.respondsToSelector("bar") {
    i.bar?()
}
else {
    i.bar()
}
```

[image]

This also means you have to modify your protocol declaration:

```
@objc protocol FooProtocol: NSObjectProtocol
```

Adding `NSObjectProtocol` allows us to call `respondsToSelector`, and doesn't really change our protocol at all.  We'd already have to be inheriting from `NSObject` in order to implement a protocol marked as `@objc`.

Of course, with all this said, any Objective-C code isn't going to be able to perform this logic on your Swift types and presumably won't be able to actually call methods implemented in these protocol extensions it seems.  So if you're trying to get something out of Apple's frameworks to call the extension method, it seems you're out of luck.  It also seems that even if you're trying to call one or the other in Swift, if it's a protocol method mark as `optional`, there's not a very great solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! So if we don't have control of the `protocol`, like Apple's frameworks, it seems we can't provide them with default implementations.

Comment: You can.  You just can't provide default implementations of ***optional*** methods in `@objc` protocols that will actually be called by any code that doesn't know about the extension.  The extension *must* be known because *only* Swift can write the correct code to call both (as far as I know) and if Swift didn't know about the extension, the correct code to call both wouldn't compile.

Comment: Yes. I meant *optional* methods. Thanks!